# Visual Studio code unable to connect to jupytner notebook

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

Have had lots of issues with this. I've had a look online and still can't work out why its so intermittent. Sometimes its able to work normally whereas others the notebook takes a long time to open and when it does I can't run anything. When trying to run something I get the following message.

Failed to connect to Jupyter notebook. 
http://localhost:8890/
TypeError: Only absolute URLs are supported

I've tried running this with all my versions of python 3.7 and 3.8

Comment: Hi IanH, I'm also having this issue, did you ever get it resolved by chance?

Comment: I didnt I'm afraid.